# cannot resolve setImageUri

Tags: android, imageview, uri

I'm trying to display an image from URI in an ImageView. I tried a few things but always got the error 'Cannot resolve the method setImageUri(android.net.uri)'.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) {
        Uri receiptUri = Uri.parse("/Kassenzettel/3.bmp");
        ImageView receiptImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.result_image);
        receiptImage.setImageUri(receiptUri);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) {
        ImageView receiptImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.result_image);

        Uri receiptUri = Uri.parse("/Kassenzettel/3.bmp");

        try {
            InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(receiptUri);
            Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromStream(inputStream, null);
            receiptImage .setImageDrawable(drawable);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
ImageView receiptImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.result_image);
Uri receiptUri = Uri.parse("/Kassenzettel/3.bmp");
InputStream inputStream = (InputStream)receiptUri.getContent();
Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromStream(inputStream, null);
receiptImage .setImageDrawable(drawable);
```